# how to create global nanoc variable between preprocessor and rule

Tags: nanoc

I create variable `@foo` in preprocessor block. It is global for the time of preprocessing, i.e. different methods can access it. However, in compilation time, i.e. in Rules, this variable is not available.

Currently, I use `@config` map to store such variables. How to create global variable that will be shared without using the `@config` map?